# How can I write the query as raw in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my query:

```
SELECT rid
FROM relations
WHERE rootid IN (736, 781) 
GROUP BY rid HAVING COUNT(rid) = 2");
```

I'm trying to implement that in Laravel. How can I do that? (both "query builder and eloquent approaches are fine to me")

---

This doesn't work: *(it throws "something went wrong")*

```
DB::table('relations')
->select('')
->whereRaw('rootid IN (736, 781)')
->groupBy('rid')
->havingRaw('COUNT(rid) = 2')
->get();
```

Comment: You can use `DB::raw()` method

Answer (score 5):

```
$sql = 'SELECT rid FROM relations WHERE rootid IN (736, 781) 
         GROUP BY rid HAVING COUNT(rid) = 2)';

$result = DB::SELECT($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
DB::table('relations')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
    ->whereRaw('rootid IN (736, 781)')
    ->groupBy('rid')
    ->having(DB::Raw('COUNT(rid) = 2'))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::table('relations')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
->whereRaw('rootid IN (736, 781)')
->groupBy('rid')
->having(DB::Raw('COUNT(rid) = 2'))
->get();
```

Comment: I've edited my code. There was a minor problem. May you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DB::table('relations')
->whereIn('rootid', [736, 781])
->groupBy('rid')
->havingRaw('COUNT(rid) = 2')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT rid
FROM relations
WHERE rootid IN (736, 781) 
GROUP BY rid HAVING COUNT(rid) = 2")'));
```